# Question with regards to fitting the yield curve with the Nelson.Siegel function from the YieldCurve package in R

Tags: programming, yield-curve

I have the following data:

```
mat <- c(88.96438,21.20548,53.06301,76.89863,112.99726,83.96712,119.80274,53.06301 ,112.99726,53.06301)
ytm <- c(0.09380442,0.07378878,0.08823629,0.09428388,0.10381418,0.09652231 ,0.10485382,0.08865775,0.10345890,0.09040975)
```

Where $mat$ are bond maturities (in months, as the function requires) and $ytm$ are the corresponding yields (in years).

I get however the following error when performing the estimation:

```
Nelson.Siegel(rate=ytm, maturity = mat)
Error in seq.default(maturity[1], maturity[pillars.number], by = 0.5) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

Can anyone please tell me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want people to help you, you really should provide a reproducible example. In particular, you should mention where the `Nelson.Siegel` function comes from. But as a guess, the maturities (`mat`) very likely have to be sorted in increasing order.

Comment: Arranging in increasing order did the trick! Thanks! And I think I could not have been more explicit about where the function Nelson.Siegel comes from, please read the tittle.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But for people (like me) who copy/paste code into R sessions,  adding a call to `require`/`library`would have helped ;-) Anyway, I am glad it worked.